# how to implement error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I have this problem in my PHP code on the following line:

```
if (!is_null($sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/')))
```

The error is :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children()
```

I know the error occurs because there are no children.

What I'd like to do is make sure the error is not triggered. I tried checking if the children exist using is_null and is_object but the error is still triggered.

I just need to hide the error message because I do not know when children will be present or not.

I hope I'm making sense.

Thanks

Comment: how you get the $xml object ?

Answer (score 1):

> I know the error occurs because there are no children.

This statement is **wrong**. The error is unrelated to the fact that there are no children. The object contained in `$sxml` does not have a method called `children` and thus the call will always result in a fatal error.

It might be a property; test this by adding a `print_r($sxml->children);` call to your code.

<strike>Besides that, a call such as `children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/')` does not make sense at all: To a function retrieving all children of a certain type you would either pass a valid XPath selector or an element. But the URL you pass is neither so even if that function existed, it would most likely fail.</strike>  - Apparently you can pass an URL to select by namespace.

Comment: First part of answer is exactly right. Second is not. [`children()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) is a method of `SimpleXMLElement`, which can be passed a uri for the namespace of the children desired, as he does here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to test  the node has children or not.

```
if($sxml->children().count()!=0) 
 {
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can catch fatal errors. Even `set_error_handler()` doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

You are **wrong** about why you are getting the error.

You are getting this error because `$sxml` ***is not a SimpleXMLElement***. Please show the code that creates `$sxml`, because that is where your problem is.

If a `SimpleXMLElement` has no children, `children()` returns an empty array. There is no fatal error.